# Pandas groupby and pivot

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have the following pandas data frame

```
   id   category    counts_mean
0   8   a           23
1   8   b           22
2   8   c           23
3   8   d           30
4   9   a           40
5   9   b           22
6   9   c           11
7   9   d           10
....
```

And I want to group by the id and transpose the category columns to get something like this:

```
  id  a  b  c  d  
0 8   23 22 23 30
1 9   40 22 11 10
```

I tried different things with groupby and pivot, but I'm not sure what should be the aggregation argument for the groupby...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using groupby and pivot, you just need to use the pivot function and set the parameters (index , columns, values) to re-shape your DataFrame.

```
#Creat the DataFrame

data = {
'id': [8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9],
'catergory': ['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'],
'counts_mean':  [23,22,23,30,40,22,11,10]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Using pivot to reshape the DF

df_reshaped = df.pivot(index='id',columns='catergory',values = 'counts_mean')
print(df_reshaped) 

output:
catergory   a   b   c   d
id                       
8          23  22  23  30
9          40  22  11  10
```

Comment: How do you conver the indices to be a column?